# How to debug an application in Android, that is started by opening a file?

Tags: android, debugging

I would like to debug an application in Android when I open a file and choose open using my app (e.g. pdf file and my app is able to read pdf). Is it possible?

I tried adding Thread.sleep to launcher activity and attaching debug to running process, but the app crashes.

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: start your app in debug mode. when the app is up and running hit Home button then go and click on your pdf file. hopefully this way you will be still in debug mode. In my case that works (please note that I am using Android studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Debug.waitForDebugger();` just before opening the file and attach a debbuger then.

Look http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Debug.html#waitForDebugger%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Don'r run and attaching debug to running process.Directly debug.